# Why is the Post model that I create in the admin panel not showing in the admin panel?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I do not understand why when I create a Post model in the admin panel, it is not displayed on my server in the admin panel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAerZ.png)

here is the code admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post
admin.site.register(Post)
```

here is the code models.py

```
from django.db import models
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
            'auth.User',
            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    body = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title`
```

I will be glad to any of your advice and help

Comment: have registered your app installed the app in settings.py and done migrations?

Comment: yes, the migrations in the tutorial do this 
`(blog) $ python manage.py makemigrations blog`

`(blog) $ python manage.py migrate blog`

and this is what I get after the first command

**No changes detected**

Answer (score 0):

> Add user app in the setting.py file like

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'corsheaders',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'dynamic_preferences.users.apps.UserPreferencesConfig',
'dynamic_preferences',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'blog',
]
```

Then makemigrations and migrate your model. I think it works for you.